# call matrix entries

Tags: matrix, slug

I set up a form structure with a matrix. Now I would like to call the entries one by one. My first idea was to loop through them, but the outcome is that the entries are displayed alltogether.

Then I tryed to call them simply by the slug. Since there are just 4 of them. Not very dynamic though.

How can I call the sets of matrix contents one by one?

```
{% set form = craft.entries({section: 'registration', slug: 'form_1',}) .first() %}
```

Didn't work. Still alltogether.

Comment: What are you going to do with them afterwards? I'm not really sure why you don't want to have them as array so you can do `form[0]`, `form[1]`

Comment: The matrix entries are displayed as registration forms on the site. I do want to have the as array. But there are several arrays which I want to show seperately. Now they show all at once.

Comment: Then you might not want to loop through the array directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get all elements from an `ElementCriteriaModel` you need to call the `find()` function

```
{% set form = craft.entries({section: 'registration'}).find() %}
```

You can them access those with normal array indexes

Comment: Can I access them with slugs? Do I need to make the slugs look like this: form[1], form[2]?

Comment: Yes you can get your entries via slug as well 
`{% set form1 = craft.entries({section: 'registration', slug: 'form_1',}) .first() %}` `{% set form2 = craft.entries({section: 'registration', slug: 'form_2',}) .first() %}` and so on. You can grab them all with one query as well, when you do `{% set forms = craft.entries({section: 'registration', slug: ['form_2', 'form_1']}).find() %}` or if the slugs are equal